# Does anybody see such an array indexing way like "2[array]"?

Tags: c++, arrays

Today, I see such a wierd way of indexing the arry.

The code is like:

```
int array[] = {10, 20, 30};
cout << -2[array];
```

I've never seen such a strange way of using array. But there is no compilation error.

Can anyone tell me does the ISO document evolve the description for this way of using array?

Comment: This is literally the second duplicate today, and the third one within two days. Can't you guys use google?

Comment: Well, acturally I did not see the duplicated one. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

It works, because expressions of the form `x[y]` is just sugar for `*(x+y)`, and of course, the addition is commutative, so `2[array]` and `array[2]` get compiled to the same thing.

Don't do it though, because it's unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: Read the question again. There is `-2`.

Comment: @haccks, is not the concept is same? `a-b` is just `a+(-b)`.

Comment: @RakibulHasan; Yes. But what I know is -ve index is invalid. `array[-2]` is not valid.

Comment: its being applied to the result, so -array[2].

Comment: @haccks, invalid index has nothing to do with compilation.

Comment: @haccks I think that is an operator priority issue.